# Help Regarding Fourier Transform of Modified Bessel Function of Second Kind

Tags: improper-integrals, fourier-transform, bessel-functions

I am looking for suggestions to evaluate this F.T which involves bessel function of the second kind (of zero order)
I = $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K_0(\sqrt{z^2+a^2}) e^{i kz} dz $$
Can this Integral I be solved analytically? Are there any analytical approximations I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$ (1) \quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty K_0(\sqrt{z^2+a^2}) \ e^{i k z} dz = \pi \, \frac{e^{-a\sqrt{k^2+1}}}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$$

The proof uses the Dirac delta function relation and a specialization of a formula from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, 6.596.7.  With that formula, let $\mu = 1/2$, $\nu=-1/2$, $\beta = z$, and $\alpha = a.$ Use the well-known reduction of the Bessel functions at odd half-integers.  Then you'll get

$$ (2) \quad K_0(\sqrt{z^2+a^2}) = \int_0^\infty \cos{zt} \  \frac{e^{-a\sqrt{t^2+1}}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}  \ dt $$

Insert (2) into the left-hand side of (1) and interchange $\int.$  The inner integral is
$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikz}\big(e^{izt} + e^{-izt} \big)dz =
\pi\big(\delta(t+k) + \delta(t-k) \big)$$
by the Fourier integral representation of the Dirac delta function.  Only the latter delta function contributes since $t>0.$

Comment: The integral in question has limits from ${-\infty}$ to ${\infty}$ whereas it is from 0 to ${\infty}$ in the solution presented. Can I get a clarification?

Comment: @vnk Corrected typo in lower limit of eq. (1).  Derivation clearly shows the intended limit in use, and the answer has been checked numerically as well.